# "Internet Explorer has stopped working" when selecting F12 Developer tools for a specific site

Tags: internet-explorer

Internet explorer 11 (latest) crashes with the message "Internet Explorer has stopped working" when opening developer tools and and I have my site open.
Chrome, Edge doesn't give the problem.

All the functionality in my site works correctly.

This is only with my site (intranet site)

[image]

When I debug it I get

> Unhandled exception at 0x5B514C32 (mshtml.dll) in iexplore.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x06EC2FFC).

How can I troubleshoot what in my site causes this behavior?

I have tried resetting Internet Explorer and disabling all add-ins but because the issue is not to do with other sites I can only think the issue is to do someone specific in the html/ javascript in my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer by removing blocks from the site until I could narrow down the problem code

In my page `head`

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
```

and commenting out the first line in that css

```
/*@import url('site.css');*/
```

Comment: In an instance that I was troubleshooting, the problem was a loop that was creating div-table sets, closing the table each time, but failing to close the div.  Thus, the next div was *nested* in the previous div.  Do that several hundred times, and IE will not be happy.

Answer (score 8):

In my case I had a CSS (font-awesome) file included twice on the layout.cshtml file causing IE to crash every time I press F12.

Removing the duplicate fixed it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/themes/base/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

Answer (score 6):

This bug [has been reported](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7115476/) to Microsoft and a demo is linked on the page. The Microsoft Edge Team provided the following statement:

> Thank you for the feedback. This appears to be fixed in Edge as I am not able to repro this. Please note that we are not working on IE feature bugs any longer unless they are security related. As a result this item will be closed out as not repro to reflect the testing results from Edge.

It doesn't look like we'll see it resolved by Microsoft.

Answer (score 6):

My laptop has 2 graphics processors: an integrated one and a a higher end nvidia one. For me the solution was to force IE11 to use the nvidia gpu. You can do this in windows by going start and searching for 'Graphics Settings'. In there you can add both the x86 and x64 iexplore.exe files and set the to 'High Performance'. Once I did this IE11 no longer crashed when I pressed F12.

[image: Graphics Settings]

Comment: Thanks! I had the same issue and this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

As both my fellow developer and I came across this question when trying to solve this issue, and still not having a clear answer to our problem until digging into the post by Microsoft in MrMcPlad's answer, I decided to make my first contribution to stackoverflow.

If you have an iFrame in your site using the same stylesheet as the main frame, it will cause this crash to occur. To debug it, remove one of the stylesheet links, and you'll be able to debug again.

Thanks, MS for not fixing a bug in the arguably superior browser. Or, you know, making it challenging for developers who want to support customers / users that don't all have Windows 10.

Comment: Arguably superior browser? Superior browser? Arguably?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, just when I delete line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

then I open Developer tools (F12) and then I restore the deleted line, the IE stays running!

Answer (score 1):

Removing duplicate CSS from Child iFrame JSP worked for me. However I need that CSS and I removed it for Debugging only and after debugging I enabled it again

Edit:
I have fixed the issue, there was a font-awesome css which was already included in parent JSP and I had included it in child JSP as well.  I removed it from child JSP and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was able to load the Developer Tools prior to opening my site. I then opened the site in another tab and hit the F12 button. this successfully opened the Developer Tools