# IE11 Closes when attempting to view source or use F12

Tags: internet-explorer-11, ie-developer-tools, view-source

We have a set of users who cannot view source or use developer tools in IE11 on Windows 10.  right clicking to view source closes the browser with no errors being displayed or found in event viewer.  If you hit F12 it will open briefly and then will again close the browser without errors

Comment: Does it exhibit the behavior on all websites or a specific one?

Comment: What is the version of IE11? Check if you have installed the latest update and try it again. You can also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37249419/internet-explorer-has-stopped-working-when-selecting-f12-developer-tools-for-a) for more information.